# Get latest post revision with wp-query

Tags: wp-query, revisions

How can I retrieve the latest revision post using wp-query?  I am trying to replicate the behaviour as when a user updates a published post and clicks on preview.

So far I've tried editing wp-query to return drafts, this works for unpublished posts but after the post is published I can not get any further edits.  I've also looked at get children, though this did not return anything useful.

Comment: updated question

Comment: Can you share the code you tried?